# Creating a UIView programmatically that retains its size when device is rotated

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, popup, popover

I am programmatically creating a UIView which will eventually become a help speech bubble for my universal app but I am having difficulty in getting the UIView to support device rotations.  When my view is created it looks great, just how I want it but when I rotate the device then my UIView popover expands to fill the entire screen which is not what I want.

I am using iOS 6 with Auto Layout for the other storyboard controls if that helps.

Could somebody please explain why iOS resizes my popover to full screen on device rotation?

I also looked at adding some constraints to it but thought that was more for the sub layers rather than the popover view itself.

The code I am using is:

```
customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];

customView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
customView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[customView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

[self.tableView.superview addSubview:customView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[customView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Flexiblewidth/height autoresizing mask resizes your UIView when the parent view changes. When the view is rotated, your superview's frame is changed and the view will change width and height proportionally. If you want the same size, remove that line, if you want the same padding around your view use

```
 [customView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying.  I just tried removing the line completely and it it still fills the entire view when I rotate, adding the second line also has the same effect.  It is if though the resizing mask has no effect?  This is all in the simulator testing on iPad view at the moment.

Comment: Try to implement - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    return YES;
}

Comment: Thanks. I reset the size in a didRotate notification instead which works so brilliant.  I can move on now.  Thanks for the help Peter.

Comment: No problem, it's strange the autoresizing mask isn't working properly. I'll have to look into it a little more.

Comment: Well, it works 99% of the time! If I hold down apple + arrow to constantly spin the simulator view then it gets its knickers in a twist every so often and the popover goes full screen but need to test on actual device now to see if thats just a simulator issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS6 apple is encouraging the use of autolayout as the code is more descriptive and easier to manage / debug.

eg. To do the same thing in autolayout

```
  UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  customView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
  customView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
  [customView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  [self.tableView.superview addSubview:customView];

  NSArray *arr;

  //horizontal constraints
  arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[customView(200)]"
                                                         options:0
                                                         metrics:nil
                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView)];
  [self.tableView.superview addConstraints:arr];

  //vertical constraints
  arr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[customView(200)]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView)];
  [self.tableView.superview addConstraints:arr];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for posting a constraint example.  I tried using them but found it confusing.  Your example compiles ok though but it still has the same effect when I rotate the device the customView fills to the screen bounds and then remains there on all device rotations.

Comment: My TableView is embedded in a Navigation Controller and Tab Bar controller, could that be causing the resizing issues?  Am I right in thinking that the superview of the tableview is the navigation controller?